# Does a Plone SelectionWidget need to be populated?

Tags: plone

I would like to put an empty selection widget on a form that will be populated later.  Here is the code:

```py
atapi.StringField(

    'catalognumber1',
    storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
    widget=atapi.SelectionWidget(
        label='Catalog Number 1',
        description=_(u"Please select the catalog number for your first conflicting class, e.g. 101"),
    ),
    required=1,
    searchable=True, 
),
```

No box shows, actually, nothing shows.  Does a selection widget need to be pre-populated?

Comment: I think so...
Every time I used a selectionWidget with nothing in it, the widget is not shown at all (except for the label)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put at least an empty vocabulary

atapi.StringField(
    'catalognumber1',
    storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
    vocabulary=( ('', '') ),

Later, substitute this with a good vocabulary (better: a vocabulary_factory)